# docker-compose persisting folder empty

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redmine

I would like use [bitnami-docker-redmine](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine) with docker-compose persisting on Windows.

If i run the first exemple docker-compose.yml, without persisting application, redmine start and run perfectly.

But, i would like use this with persisting application exemple :

```
version: '2'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: 'bitnami/mariadb:latest'
        environment:
            - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
        volumes:
            - './mariadb:/bitnami/mariadb'
    redmine:
        image: bitnami/redmine:latest
        ports:
            - 80:3000
        volumes:
            - './redmine:/bitnami/redmine'
```

And only MariaDB run, with error message :

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating bitnamidockerredmine_redmine_1
Creating bitnamidockerredmine_mariadb_1
Attaching to bitnamidockerredmine_mariadb_1, bitnamidockerredmine_redmine_1
mariadb_1  |
mariadb_1  | Welcome to the Bitnami mariadb container
mariadb_1  | Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb
mariadb_1  | Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb/issues
mariadb_1  | Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
mariadb_1  |
mariadb_1  | WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
mariadb_1  | nami    INFO  Initializing mariadb
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO  ==> Configuring permissions...
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO  ==> Validating inputs...
mariadb_1  | mariadb WARN  Allowing the "rootPassword" input to be empty
redmine_1  |
redmine_1  | Welcome to the Bitnami redmine container
redmine_1  | Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine
redmine_1  | Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redmine/issues
redmine_1  | Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
redmine_1  |
redmine_1  | nami    INFO  Initializing redmine
redmine_1  | redmine INFO  Configuring Redmine database...
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO  ==> Initializing database...
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO  ==> Creating 'root' user with unrestricted access...
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO  ==> Enabling remote connections...
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO  ########################################################################
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO   Installation parameters for mariadb:
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO     Root User: root
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO     Root Password: Not set during installation
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO   (Passwords are not shown for security reasons)
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO  ########################################################################
mariadb_1  | mariadb INFO
mariadb_1  | nami    INFO  mariadb successfully initialized
mariadb_1  | INFO  ==> Starting mariadb...
mariadb_1  | nami    ERROR Unable to start com.bitnami.mariadb: Warning: World-writable config file '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/my.cnf' is ignored
mariadb_1  | Warning: World-writable config file '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/my.cnf' is ignored
mariadb_1  |
bitnamidockerredmine_mariadb_1 exited with code 1
redmine_1  | mysqlCo INFO  Trying to connect to MySQL server
redmine_1  | Error executing 'postInstallation': Failed to connect to mariadb:3306 after 36 tries
bitnamidockerredmine_redmine_1 exited with code 1
```

My ./mariadb folder is good, but ./redmine is empty.

Do you have any idea why my persisting does not start completely ? Without the persisting, it works :(

```
docker-version : 1.13.0 (client/server)
plateform : Windows 10 (sorry, not test on Linux)
```

Thank you !

Comment: What happens if your run the docker compose (with persisitent) multiple times without killing the mariadb? (is redmine that able to start up in a right way?)

Comment: Hi, i've test on Linux, and it work. The problem is only on windows :/